# Any way or solution to convert the string data from JSON API to int in js?

Tags: reactjs, calendar, int

Consider the code below:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    const id = localStorage.getItem('id');



     fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/calendar/list/${id}`,)
     .then((resp)=>{
       resp.json().then((res)=>{
          this.setState({
            data: res.data.map(item => {
              return {
                title: item.title,
                startDate: new Date(item.startDate),
                endDate: new Date(item.endDate),
                eventId: item.eventType  // from api it provide on string but I need to convert it in to an integer
              };

            })
          });
       })
     })

   }
```

The result from the API are here:

[image]

So on the frontend js, I need to set the eventId to a number like **Conference in num 1**, **Launching in num 2**, **Trade Shows in num 3**. Is it any way I can do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object to map the string to a number like this, where `item1` and `item2` are examples of what your API data could be:

```js
const item1 = {
  userId: 1,
  startDate: 123456,
  endDate: 123456,
  eventType: 'Conference'
};
const item2 = {
  userId: 2,
  startDate: 123456,
  endDate: 123456,
  eventType: 'Launching'
};

const map = { Conference: 1, Launching: 2, Trade: 3 };

console.log(map[item1.eventType]); // eventId will be 1 for Conference
console.log(map[item2.eventType]); // eventId will be 2 for Launching
```

In your code this would be

```
const map = { Conference: 1, Launching: 2, Trade: 3 };
fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/calendar/list/${id}`,)
     .then((resp)=>{
       resp.json().then((res)=>{
          this.setState({
            data: res.data.map(item => {
              return {
                title: item.title,
                startDate: new Date(item.startDate),
                endDate: new Date(item.endDate),
                eventId: map[item.eventType]
              };
            })
          });
       })
     })
```

Comment: @kokoka no problem

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `Switch Case` if you know all the values

```
getEventId = eventType => {
  switch (eventType){
    case 'Conference'
      return 1;

      ...... // rest of the cases

     }
   }
}
```

Then use this function to map eventType to eventId

```
eventId: getEventId(item.eventType)
```